# Copy2Contact Rest API return different response on every refresh/reload against the same Input text

Tags: php, web-services, api

I am using copy2contact rest Api that gives me different response against the same input text on every reload or refresh.

***http://www.copy2contact.com/api/rest.php***

```
    ob_start();
    $text = "John Smith
            123 Spruce Ln.
            Boston, MA 01234
            cell: 676-144-8901
            johnjohn7202@gmail.com";
    $text = urlencode($text);
    $url = "https://api.copy2contact.com/rest/json/ParseContact?text=" . $text . "&emu&authid=1329&pass=123456";
    $curl_request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($curl_request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 200) {

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        echo $result;
        curl_close($curl_request);
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        $http_message = curl_error($curl_request);
        var_dump('Error: "' . $http_message . '" having error code ' . $http_code);
        return '';
    }
```

**RESPONSE:**
"{"result":{"ContactPreNameTitle":"","ContactName":"Smitv","ContactFirst":"Jahn","ContactMiddle":"","ContactPostNameTitles":"","ContactTitle":"","ContactCompany":"","ContactAddress":"722 Spruce............"

***When I reload then the response change.***
that is " {"result":{"ContactPreNameTitle":"","ContactName":"Smpth","ContactFirst":"Rohn","ContactMiddle":"","ContactPostNameTitles":"","ContactTitle":"","ContactCompany":"","ContactAddress":"023 Sqruce.............."

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas from Copy2Contact here. The issue is that developer accounts produce slightly obfuscated results so that you can't use the account in a production setting. A few letters are changed at random, but you can still see that the result produced by the parser is accurate.

Feel free to contact us with any other questions.